# IO redirection to another file

Tags: linux, shell, redirect, io, io-redirection

I'm trying to change my grades in a text file, and then direct the output to a new text file using the >> operator instead of overwriting the old file.

But, the text file has a significant amount of other students results in the file, and the file is laid out in this type of way that each line contains the results of one exam for one student, so there are multiple lines for a student depicting the different exam results for the different exams.

How would I specifically search for a grade that is either "A,B,C,D" and beside my name "Joe Bloggs", on different lines?

ty men

Comment: Have you tried using `grep`?

Comment: Well I don't have access to my other computer till tomorrow, would it be something along the lines of this? I dont know how I'd search for the line with my name on it. ls -R | grep ^a,b,c,d | >> bacon.txt

Comment: you need to edit your question and include 2 types of sample data, some of "your" data, and 2nd, some from another student. You also need to show what you expect your output to look. Use 4 spaces at the fron of each line so the data will be properly formatted. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `grep` command:

```
cat grades.txt | grep "Joe Bloggs" | grep "A\|B\|C\|D" >> output.txt
```

If you wanted to change all `B, C, or D's` beside `Joe Bloggs` to all `A's`, you'll use sed like so:

```
cat grades.txt | grep "Joe Bloggs" | grep "A\|B\|C\|D" | sed 's/\(B\|C\|D\)/A/g' >> output.txt
```

Using `awk`:

```
cat grades.txt | grep "Joe Bloggs" | grep "A\|B\|C\|D" | awk '{gsub(/B|C|D/,"A");print}' >> output.txt
```

Using `perl`:

```
cat grades.txt | grep "Joe Bloggs" | grep "A\|B\|C\|D" | perl -e "s/B|C|D/A/" -p >> output.txt
```

Comment: So is that command going to find all the A's on the same line as my name, or the A's on every line? Lastly, how do you change for example b,c,d to an A in the output file?

Comment: @Rapidz This command will save the entire line that has `Joe Bloggs` **and** `A or B or C or D` on the same line throughout the entire file.

Comment: That's it james, I was looking here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/searching-multiple-words-string-using-grep/ and this is what I will try tomorrow, but is there no way to change the string to the new file with grep or will sed have to be used?

Comment: Thanks James, I'd give you rep if I could. Is the only way to change the string with sed?

Comment: @Rapidz You'll have to use `sed`, `awk`, or `perl` to do the modifications. I'll show you an example of each.